# Using extendscript (javascript) how can I get the color values from the Photoshop color table

Tags: photoshop, extendscript

I'm writing a Photoshop script in extendscript/javascript and I'm trying to verify that the document is using just one color (plus transparency).  What I would like to do is change the document mode to Indexed Color and then get the values in the color table.

I have successfully changed the document mode to Indexed Color but can't figure out how to access the color table or the color values inside of it.

My working alternative is to use a colorSampler to compare the values of each pixel, but that can take a couple of minutes to run on larger documents and speed is an issue for this project.

Please let me know if there is a way to access the color table or if you see a way to reduce the time it takes to run this function.

```
function sample_color(doc, sample_rate) {
    var status = 'PASS'
    var color_sampler = doc.colorSamplers.add([0,0])
    var color_val = false  //first (and hopefully only) color value in the document
    var broke = false
    for (x=1; x < doc.width; x+=sample_rate){
        if (broke){
            break
        }
        for (y=1; y < doc.height; y+=sample_rate){
            color_sampler.move([UnitValue(x, 'px'), UnitValue(y, 'px')])
            try{
                var color = color_sampler.color  //color of the current pixel
            } catch(e) {
                var color = false  //color_sampler.color fails if the pixel is transparent
            }
            if (color != false){
                if (color_val != false){
                    if (!color.isEqual(color_val)){
                        status = 'FAIL'
                        broke = true
                        break
                    }
                } else {
                    color_val = color
                }
            }
        }
    }
    color_sampler.remove()
    return status
}
```

Answer (score 0):

xbytor has written a couple of scripts for accessing colour tables. This [link](http://forums.adobe.com/message/2209288#2209288) may be of use to you.

Comment: I looked through the examples from xbytor, but didn't see how to access the color table in Photoshop without writing out a temporary GIF.

I ended up using the histogram.  The first step was to duplicate the document.  In the duplicate, hide the other layers/groups.  Merge the visible layers.  Select non-transparent pixels.  Check the values in the histogram for each channel.  If there is more than one value greater than 0 in a histogram, there is more than one color in the layer.

Comment: Had you thought to write out a .act palete file instead (obviously it's difficult to access it internally) They are pretty straight forward as files go.